# CompletableFuture - Run multiple rest calls throwing java.util.concurrent.CompletionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

I have a service that makes 2 calls to another service and then combines the responses and generates a response.

```
public HashMap<String,Double> getResp(String requestJson, double defaultScore, String anomalySelfInclUrl,String anomalySelfExclUrl){
        CompletableFuture<Double> f1 = getHelper(requestJson,anomalySelfInclUrl);
        CompletableFuture <Double>f2=  getHelper(requestJson,anomalySelfExclUrl);
        AnomalyResponse anomalyResponse =new AnomalyResponse();
        HashMap<String,Double> respMap= new HashMap<>();
        CompletableFuture.allOf(f1,f2)
                .thenRun(() -> {
                    try {
                        Double anomalySelfModelRes = f1.get();
                        Double anomalyExclModelRes = f2.get();
                        respMap.put(Constants.selfInc,anomalySelfModelRes);
                        respMap.put(Constants.selfExcl,anomalyExclModelRes);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }).join();
        return respMap;
    }

public CompletableFuture<Double> getHelper(String requestJson, String url)  {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestJson, headers);
            String resp =restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
            JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(resp).getAsJsonObject();
            return json.get("score").getAsDouble();
        });

    }
```

In the getResp method , I am using completable future to create 2 post calls (via getHelper method).
Once both the post call is completed I am adding them to a HashMap and returning that.
But I am getting the following error in the **postForObject()** method.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException
```

**The error seems to be happening as  the called service is not receiving the posted json data and the header (wrapped in the HttpEntity).
How can this happen ? The issue does not appear during sequential calls.**

Comment: Suppose that you have checked whether the same code runs sequentially(ie not with async futures). In case it is, then have to confirm whether the passed restTemplate is actually causing the issue (it shouldn't as the instance is thread safe), otherwise, there is another nested exception, swallowed by the CompletableFuture , without safe catches.

Answer (score 1):

If there is exception while executing the method within completable future, it throws completion exception.

So lets say you get a 401 from your API & your `restTemplate` will throws a Unauthorized exception. It will be wrapped within a CompletionException.

You can get actual response from `objOfCompletionException.getCause()` method call. It will have all the details of what actually cased the exception.

Comment: I have updated the question now.Seems like the posted HttpEntity is not getting received at the called service end